# extract substring of string

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

How to extract `3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477` from the following string?

```
mysql-bin.000025    217141189   3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
```

It is fetched via `line=$(head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info)`

Comment: Does echo $line | awk ‘{ sub(/,/,””,$3); print $3 }’ work?

Comment: Are these fields separated by space, or by tabs (or a combination of both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $line | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $3}'
```

That uses `echo` to print the value of `$line` and then uses `awk` to set the delimiter as either a space or a `,` and prints the third field.

Output:

```
3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477
```

If you are doing it with `head` and not `echo $line` then the output is achieved with:

```
head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $8}'
```

It is important to be clear about which method you want to use in your question.

Comment: the output is empty

Comment: @clarkk Are you using GNU `awk` and are you actually setting `$line` in the way that you have in the question? I have tested this with GNU `awk` and I get your expected output.

Comment: `# head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $3}'`

Comment: I'm on Debian 10

Comment: @clarkk Nasir's command and mine work with your sample, there's something missing here.

Comment: how do I know which version of `awk` is installed?

Comment: @clarkk I have updated my answer to account for the use of the `head` command. If that's what you want to use, you need to make sure that you specify that in the question.

Comment: @clarkk `awk --version`. As it is Debian 10, you have GNU `awk`.

Comment: the output is still empty.. If I omit the part with `awk` the first line of the file is printed

Comment: If I do this `awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $1}'` the whole string is printed

Comment: @clarkk Then there is something that you aren't clarifying or something that you are doing differently. As schrodigerscatcuriousity mentioned, both his and my answers work.

Comment: @clarkk Try it now. I forgot to change `$3` to `$8` in the second command. I have confirmed that this works in Debian 10. You could also just use the first command or else there is no reason to have command substitution to set the `$line` variable.

Comment: I have copy pasted your command with `print $8` but the output is still empty

Comment: @clarkk Then like I said, there is something that you aren't mentioning. Both of the answers here work.

Comment: No, I do what I have told you.. `head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info` prints the first line..

Comment: @clarkk what happens with `head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $1}'`?

Comment: the whole line is printed

Comment: the whole line except the `,` in the end

Comment: @clarkk Then you just confirmed that you aren't doing exactly what you stated. The command from schrodiger prints `mysql-bin.000025`. `awk` doesn't function in a way that the command would print the entire line. The first command also works which you may as well use after setting it via command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Like this with `awk`:

```bsh
$ line="$(head -n 1 ./xtrabackup_binlog_info)"

$ echo "$line" | awk -F'[[:blank:]]+|,' '{ print $3 }'
3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477
```

Comment: this only returns `i`

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[,[:blank:]]+"; }; { print $(NF-1); exit; }'
```